# focus Using Jquery <tr> <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(this).closest('tr').next() td:eq(7).focus();
```

What is the error in this? I am new to jQuery. How can I focus using `tr`, `td` and `table` index?

```
$('.gridfield').keypress(function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    if (e.which == 13) {    
        var row_index = $(this).parent().index();    
        $(this).closest('tr').next() td:eq(row_index).focus();     
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').next().find('td').eq(row_index).focus();     `

Comment: Not working... any other solution for this...?

Comment: what are you trying to do? share the html sample what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax isn't quite right. You can use either this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().find('td').eq(row_index).focus();
```

Or this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().find('td:eq(' + row_index + ')').focus();
```

They are logically identical.

> Each cell contains input field

In that case use either one of these:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().find('td').eq(row_index).find('input').focus(); 
$(this).closest('tr').next().find('td:eq(' + row_index + ') input').focus();
```

Comment: Well, you wouldn't see any visible effect of focusing a `td`, I assumed you had an event hooked to it. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: i am looking for events like in MS Excel. Eg: When i press the Enter button the courser move down  by 1 cell in table and also when i press arrow keys the courser go up,down,left and right. Same as MS Excel.

Comment: Each cell contains input field.

Comment: In that case you need to focus the input directly. I updated my answer for you